# At what point do the 'original' endings for Cyberpunk 2077 get locked out?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077, cyberpunk-2077-phantom-liberty

There's multiple possible endings for cyberpunk. Pre Phantom Liberty they all branched off at the same point, and once you'd reached that point of the game, you could go back once you'd completed the game or from a saved game. Phantom Liberty unlocks a new set of endings and I'd like to have a manual saved game that would let me use the character I've built up to do both the 'new' phantom liberty endings *or* the regular ones.

Do the original endings get locked out if you complete phantom liberty and does that have any effect on the rest of the game?

Answer (score 5):

While the DLC technically has 4 different endings, it only adds one new ending ([The Tower](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/The_Tower_(achievement))) to the base game. In 2 of the 4 endings, you will receive the [Who Wants to Live Forever](https://www.ign.com/wikis/cyberpunk-2077/Who_Wants_to_Live_Forever_Walkthrough) mission. There is a Point of No Return during this mission, that will lock you out of the original endings.

Answer (score 3):

Raj's answer is not wrong, but perhaps this one is more helpful for players who've not played Phantom Liberty before.

Phantom Liberty has four endings. In two of them you will receive the Who Wants to Live Forever mission, which once started will lock you out of the original endings (and all remaining quests/activities in the game). Like most other quests in the game, however, you can take your time before starting this quest. The other two endings will end Phantom Liberty storyline, but the game goes on. You'll have to go into one of the original endings to end the game.

The four endings are conditional on a choice you make in the [Firestarter](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/Firestarter) quest, for which there is no Point of No Return warning. Therefore, if you want to experience all the endings, *make a manual save here*, and possibly another one in the next main job.

Answer (score -1):

No. You do not get locked out of any endings by completing the DLC.

One of the DLC endings allows you to later choose a different ending at the end of the game. But this is a choice you make at the end of the game, and you can always decide not to and just go for a different ending.